# Unexplained junk value in variable

Tags: c, memory, bison, flex-lexer

Iam trying to compile a file of the following format by making a parser in bison

```
LOCATION house
NAME "House"
DESCRIPTION "You are standing\nin front of your house.\nPaths lead towards east and west."
east flag
west forest

LOCATION obelisk
NAME "Obelisk"
DESCRIPTION "A big obelisk is\nstanding before you. You can either go east or west or  south." 
south flag
east flag
west treasure
```

My parser has a function

```
int find(char *id) {
int i;
for(i=0;i<nLoc;i++) {
if(strcmp(id,tmp_idList[i]) == 0){
    printf(tmp_idList[0]);
    printf(" i = %d returned",i);
return i;

    }
}

printf("Copying...");
strcpy(tmp_idList[nLoc],id);
printf("%d %s",nLoc,tmp_idList[nLoc]);
nLoc++;
printf(" nloc-1 = %d returned",nLoc-1);
return (nLoc-1);
}
```

It uses

```
char tmp_idList[60][100];
```

Grammar is (relevant here )

```
locnSpec : tok_LOCN tok_IDENT nameSpec descrSpec exitList
            {int k = find($2);
             locList[k].name = strdup(tmp_name);
             locList[k].descr = strdup(tmp_descr);
             memcpy(locList[k].exits, 
                    tmp_exit,
                    4*sizeof(int));}
```

Now when i run this code, somehow

```
 tmpidList[0]
```

is getting populated with a junk value as shown below in the output

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.



C:\Users\MY PC\Desktop\final>bison -d -o compile.c adv6.y

C:\Users\MY PC\Desktop\final>gcc -o compile compile.c lex.yy.c

C:\Users\MY PC\Desktop\final>compile<toy.al



 Copying...0 flag nloc-1 = 0 returned
 Copying...1 forest nloc-1 = 1 returned

Copying...2 house nloc-1 = 2 returned


 flag i = 0 returned // OK HERE
 flag i = 0 returned
 Copying...3 treasure nloc-1 = 3 returned

Copying...4 obelisk nloc-1 = 4 returned



Copying...5 marsh nloc-1 = 5 returned


 nd west. i = 4 returned // JUNK HERE
 Copying...6 flag nloc-1 = 6 returned
 nd west. i = 1 returned

nd west. i = 3 returned


 t. i = 4 returned
 t. i = 2 returned
 t. i = 4 returned

t. i = 6 returned


 t. i = 5 returned
 t. i = 2 returned
 t. i = 3 returned

t. i = 1 returned t. i = 2 returned


C:\Users\MY PC\Desktop\final>
```

As a cue when i tried allocating memory via malloc

```
char* tmp_idList[20]

...

tmp_idList[nLoc] = malloc(strlen(id) +1 )
```

it worked fine till flag was there in tmp_idList[0] but stopped working and there was a memory error in compile.exe.

does anyone has clue on what is happening? if you want more information , i can provide. i really need help for my college project.

Comment: Use *string* C++ class instead of *char**

Comment: Alternately, don't tag a question about c with [c++].

Comment: I've removed the C++ tag; it seemed to be an artifact of the collectively subconscious mythical language called "C/C++".

Comment: Perhaps if you don't know how to organize your code, you could start by organizing your question.  You post sniplets of your grammar and input files, and then complain about errors that happen *outside* of them.  How are we supposed to help you?  Please boil down a compilable example that shows your problem.  In most cases, this isolation process also brings the bug to light, so you may not even have to ask the question afterwards.

Comment: `printf(tmp_idList[0])` is a poor idea because it interprets `tmp_idList[0]` as a `printf` format string.

Comment: By the way, it's not "junk" that the variable gets overwritten with. It's the last part of the DESCRIPTION text. So all you need to do is find out where in your code this DESCRIPTION gets set/loaded/copied and you've got the location of your error.

Comment: Yeah i figured that out and reduced the length of description and it was okay but a deep analysis is needed which i am going to do after so many valuable answers . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One note. Your `find` function might be called `intern`. What it does is reduce a string token to a numeric atom. If it has not seen the string before, it returns a new atom, but it if it is called twice with the same string, it returns the same atom each time. This is called interning which originated in the Lisp language.

You have some issues in that code since your symbols have space for 100 character names, but you are not checking this, and just using blind strcpy.

Now about this grammar rule:

locnSpec : tok_LOCN tok_IDENT nameSpec descrSpec exitList
               {int k = find($2);
                locList[k].name = strdup(tmp_name);
                locList[k].descr = strdup(tmp_descr);
                memcpy(locList[k].exits, 
                       tmp_exit,
                       4*sizeof(int));}

What if a location spec occurs twice for the same location? You just leak this memory by overwriting `locList[k].name`. You might want to free the old value that was there before. If these structures are initialized to null/zeros, you can do this:

free(locList[k].name);
   locList[k].name = strdup(tmp_name);

Secondly, where do these `tmp_name` and `tmp_descr` variables come from? Are these globals that were stuffed with values during the reduction of the `namesSpec` and `descrSpec` nonterminal symbols?

That's a nasty approach; you really should be using the Yacc stack to return semantic values and refer to them via $3, $4 and $5.

As for the corruption problem you're chasing; it is quite possibly a static array overrun. You are not doing any bounds checking on anything.

The gist of the problem is this:

```
/* two arrays, probably located side by side in the executable image */
static char array1[20][30];
static char array2[40][20];
```

If you access `array1` beyond its end, you will likely trash some other variable, like perhaps `array2`, depending on how things are laid out in the run-time image.

One thing you can do, in the absence of more advanced debugging tools, is to step through the code in the debugger and monitor the contents of the overwritten variable. Try to catch the program "red handed" changing that value.

Secondly, the contents of that trashed array should give you a clue about where that material came from! It appears to be a fragment of text, which can be traced back to your input, and from there you can trace where that part of the input is handled in your parsing machine.

Comment: I understand the problem now . I will try to correct it. I somehow reduced the size of strings and got it working but i will debug it your way. thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
tmp_idList = malloc(strlen(id) +1 )
```

Also I suggest you using C++ *string* class instead of *char**. It's more prone to error for beginners that don't fully understand C pointers and memory allocation (which looks like you do).

Comment: i dont think i can use c++ strings because bison generates a c file